# insert row in a table view without storing datasource in code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have drawn my tableView in storyBoard with static cells and multiple sections. 6 sections each has proper number of static cells. In code, in MyTableViewController I do not implement any of the datasource or delegate methods, which logically means I do not have my model in code, the array or whatever that dataSource methods will use to populate number of sections or number of rows in a section. My question is: is it possible to insert a row to any of the sections?

I read a lot of stack questions. All of them is based on having a model array or dictionary that plays its role in dataSource methods to construct the table.

I have my table already constructed in storyBoard. I can get my number of sections with tableView.numberofSections() for example. Which means the model is stored somewhere for sure. I just need a proper method to get access to that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason the UITableView works the way it does with the datasource protocol.  It allows iOS to use just what is needed to display on the screen at any given time as you scroll through the table, making it very efficient.  Without implementing the required methods, iOS will not know how to rebuild the cell if you scroll it off the screen and then back on.

If you don't need that complexity (and really, it isn't complex and you can implement the required methods in less time than it is taking me to respond), you could use a UIStackView inside of a UIScrollView.  It would allow you to simply add a set of UI components vertically down the screen, complete with scrolling.

Can you explain why you don't want to implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Comment: The reason not to use dataSource protocol is because I am drawing my tableview in storyBoard, and I know how to implement those methods. Thank you for your suggestions, but they do not provide the answer to my question. My question is not the complexity of implementing datasource methods, and neither it is the what will be the alternative method. And also it is not because I do not want to implement the protocol but more like the curiosity.

Comment: Actually, I did answer your question.  It is not possible.  I tried to help by explaining why it wasn't possible, as well as trying to understand your reason for not implementing the required code for it to work in iOS.  I also gave you an alternative, if you don't want to write code.  Put a UIStackView into a UIScrollView and build it all in the Interface Builder (in your storyboard).  This is not Visual Studio.  You will have to right code in order to create an app that works correctly and efficiently in iOS.

Comment: Now after you say it is not possible, I understood your answer.